# chunking array class in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, chunking

I am trying to create a chunking class in typescript, since I keep reusing the same code over and over based on: [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Here is what I have:

```js
export class array_chunk {

    arr = [];
    chunk: number;

    constructor(arr: any, chunk: number) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.chunk = chunk;
    }

    forEachChunk(funct: Function) {
        for (let i = 0, j = this.arr.length; i < j; i += this.chunk) {
            const temparray = this.arr.slice(i, i + this.chunk);
            temparray.forEach((ta: any) => {
                funct();
            });
        }
    }
}

/// usage?

let me = new array_chunk([5, 4, 3], 1);
me.forEachChunk((chunkArray: any) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(chunkArray));
    return chunkArray;
});
```

I can't wrap my head around it it.  Basically, I would like something similar to **forEach** but for the chunks. Then I could **forEach** that.  Am I close?  I realize there should be different ways of thinking about this as my example is just conjecture.

EDIT --> here is the SOLUTION code I ended up using thanks to @skovy

```js
class array_chunk {

    arr: any[];
    chunk: number;

    constructor(arr: any[], chunk = 100) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.chunk = chunk;
    }

    forEachChunk(funct: Function) {
        for (let i = 0, j = this.arr.length; i < j; i += this.chunk) {
            const tempArray = this.arr.slice(i, i + this.chunk);
            funct(tempArray);
        }
    }
}

/// usage

let me = new array_chunk([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4], 3);
me.forEachChunk((chunkArray: any[]) => {
        console.log("chunk");
    chunkArray.forEach((ca) => {
        console.log(ca);
    })
    return chunkArray;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `forEachChunk` expects a callback for each element in which that chunk will be passed. However, in the actual implementation, it's invoked as `funct()` without passing any argument.

Have you tried updating this call to pass the chunk: `funct(ta)`.